# Excel vba: Informative modal window (blocking for the user, non-blocking for the macro)

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro excel that makes many things. One of those things is to run a query (via ADODB.Connection). The query can last a lot, so I would like:

- Show a modal informative dialog, saying "running query 3" (for example), without any buttons (the user shouln't be able to close it). It should be blocking for the user, but non-bloking for the macro.
- Run the query.
- Close the informative window.

In pseudo-code:

```
dim cn as new ADODB.Connection
dim rs as new ADODB.Recordset

dim dia as InfoDialog
set dia = new InfoDialog "running query 3"

cn.Open cn_string
rs.Open query_string, cn, ...

dia.close
```

I would prefer a solution without having to import new libraries (vba editor > tools > references). For example, with something similar to 'CreateObject("WScript.Shell")'. If not possible, then library import is welcome too (preferablily standard libraries, for not having to install things in users' computers).

---

**Update**: Following Kenda's suggestion, I have made a userForm "InfoDialog" with a label "Label1", and created two library functions to make it easy to use:

```
sub show_info(text as string)

    InfoDialog.Label1.Caption = text
    InfoDialog.Show
    DoEvents

end sub

sub close_info()

    InfoDialog.Hide

end sub
```

So now I can write:

```
show_info "Connecting to db ..."
cn.Open cn_string

show_info "Running query ..."
rs.Open query_string, cn, ...

close_info
```

Comment: adapt [progress bar](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just insert UserForm with Label than in your code you can use

```
Form1.Show
Form1.Label1.Text="running query 3"
...
Form1.Hide
```

on the end optional unload form with `Unload Form1`

Answer (score 0):

I've another problem with running macro. When I run large code, an Excel 2010 looks like it freeze, but macro still running on backround. And user haven't ProgressBar. So I use some trick with Label with blue BackColor in Frame. (Contains: Label named lblDescription, Fram named FrameProgress where is Label named LabelProgress)
[image]

For nonFreezing make this:
1) add Sub on Activate form

```
Private Sub UserForm_activate()
    Call ImportDat
End Sub
```

2) in Module1 make starting Sub

```
Sub ShowDialog()
    UserForm1.LabelProgress.Width = 0
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

3) in Module1 make your Sub with this code (magic word is `DoEvents`)

```
Sub ImportDat()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim RowMax As Integer    
Dim PctDone As Single
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Counter = 1
  RowMax = 10000
  For i = 0 To RowMax -1 
    PctDone = i / RowMax
    With UserForm1
      .lblDescription = "Processing " + CStr(i + 1) + " from " + CStr(RowMax)
      .FrameProgress.Caption = Format(PctDone, "0%")
      .LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
    End With
    DoEvents
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Hope it helps you.